# Access Denied Error using Azure Cache

Tags: .net, caching, exception, azure, appfabric

I have an application that uses App Fabric Cache.  The application works fine Onpremise, but when I publish it to Azure, I get an Access Denied error when cache is being accessed.

I have configured my Azure deployment's web.config to contain the Cache client settings that exist in the Azure mamangement application. My cache in Azure is also setup and has an "Active" status.

What could I be doing wrong? Am I missing a configuration step?

Comment: What version of the Azure SDK and Azure App Fabric SDK are you using?

Answer (score 0):

What might be happening is that the item that is stored in the cache is not available once it's deployed.  For example if `MyProject.Cache.Foo` which is in the assembly `MyProject.Cache` is available on your local deployment, but this isn't available when deployed to the cloud you can get this error.

You can end up in this situation either when you haven't included the assembly it you cloud deployment (check the Copy Local properties of all of the references that you're using) or if you've renamed/moved the class.  e.g. if you put a `MyProject.Cache.Bar` into the cache with a key of "B", then you rename the class to `MyProject.Cache.Foo`, because by default items stay in the cache indefinitely, when you try to get out the item with a key of "B" you get a "Can't find file" error.

Comment: I am using App Fabric SDK v1.3. I am not sure but the error may be during initialization of the cache. I have a flag that disables the use of cache and when it is turned off, the application works fine. Copy local is set to true for both Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core and Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Client.  I believe these are the only two assemblies I need for caching.

Comment: If it's not either of these problems, then we'll need more information.  How do you know you're getting an access denied error?  Can you post the full error message?  Have you tried removing the caching functionality to check that is actually the cause of the problem?

Comment: I will dig deeper to try and obtain the inner exception but the main exception message is "Access is denied". When I disable the use of cache I do not get the error.